# Alert button action not working in swift

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I have a alerviewcontroller with multiple buttons . These buttons are created based on a array value . My code is given below and the button action dont work properly.

```
 var alert : UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Select student", message: nil , preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    for var j = 0; j < self.students.count; j++ {


        var student: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: self.students[j], style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){

            UIAlertAction  in

            for var i = 0; i < self.students.count ; i++ {

                if alert.title == self.students[i]{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.loader.startAnimating()
                println(i)
                self.studentLabel.text = self.students[i]
            })


            self.loadTimeTable(self.studentId[i])

                }

            }
        }

        alert.addAction(student)

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only creating `alert` not `invoking` it.
 Add this line at the end

```
 self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```